# Typescript casting object's property

Tags: properties, casting, typescript

I'm working with indexeddb and typescript. My issue is that TS doesn't seem to be able handle the `event.target.result` property. Case in point:

```
request.onsuccess = (event) => {
    namespace.db = event.target.result; //the property 'results' does not 
                                        //exist on the value of type 'EventTarget'
    var a = event.target;
    var b = <IDBOpenDBRequest>a;
    var c = b.result; // <-- magically there's a results property here

    version = parseInt(namespace.db.version);
    console.log("version: " + version);
    deferred.resolve();
}
```

So my question is: Is there an easier way to cast the `target` property to `<IDBOpenDBRequest>` other then the `a`, `b` method above?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are looking for a oneliner you can cast it by adding some extra parenthesis like so:

```
indexedDB.open("test", 1).onsuccess = (ev) => {
    var result: IDBDatabase = (<IDBOpenDBRequest>ev.target).result;
}
```

Also notice the `: IDBDatabase` because result is typed as `any` in the Typescript definition file. It isn't needed but using it as an "any" type would mean no typechecking by the compiler.

Now you can use the result like you want with the methods available as defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#database-interface

Comment: Thanks. I face-palmed when I saw your answer. I don't know why I didn't think of that. Works like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

You can also cast using the 'as' keyword like this

```
interface MyCustomUserInterface {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
}

const userID = (req.user as MyCustomUserInterface)._id
...
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to chain, you can do this:

```js
const chargeId = (<Stripe.Invoice>subscription.latest_invoice).charge as string;
```

...with 3 properties:

```js
    const paymentIntent = (<Stripe.Invoice>subscription.latest_invoice).payment_intent as Stripe.PaymentIntent;
    
    const secret = paymentIntent.client_secret;
```