# Angular2: Error - Property 'updateValue' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'

Tags: typescript, webstorm, angular

I've created a **ControlGroup** `theForm` using **FormBuilder**.

When I tried to update value of a control like this

`this.theForm.find('MainImageId').updateValue( id, true, true);`

It worked fine but WebStorm shows an error saying

`Error:(148, 24) TS2339: Property 'updateValue' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

What am I doing wrong? and why does it work?

Comment: That's at runtime, WebStorm doesn't have runtime information. Check the return type in the source code of `theForm.find()`

Comment: Gotcha. It's AbstractControl , see angular's gitHub [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.0/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/model.ts#L305-L411).
But what should I do ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Typescript casting object's property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490535/typescript-casting-objects-property) I guess this should fix it

`find` is now `get` (>=RC.5)

```
   (<Control> this.theForm.find('MainImageId')) .updateValue( id, {onlySelf:true, emitEvent:true});

   // (<Control> this.theForm.find('MainImageId')) .updateValue( id, {onlySelf:true, emitEvent:true});
```

Edit: Optional parameters are supplied as an Object in second parameter.

Comment: Nicely Done! but it only accepts one parameter while expected to accept at least 1 and up to 4 as described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.0/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/model.ts#L239-L305). so `updateValue( id);` gives no error
but `updateValue( id, true, true);` says 
`Error:(146, 5) TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

Comment: You might need some `{}` around the optional parameters, but here it seems I reached my TS limits. Maybe someone else can provide some info.